# Disablling scrolling of a scroll bar while keeping it visible in wxPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, user-controls, wxpython

I am currently working with wxPython v3.0, python v2.7 on Windows 7 OS. I have question regarding the scroll bars. In my application I have a GUI which has many scrolled panels. The scroll bar of these scrolled panels are working fine too.

**Problem:** My question is that is it possible to disable the scrolling of a scroll bar while keeping it visible on a particular scrolled panel? *The scroll bar shouldn't scroll when being clicked on the scroll buttons or by dragging the scroll bar*.

I know that we can disable horizontal or vertical scrolling by using `SetupScrolling(scroll_y=False)` and `SetupScrolling(scroll_x=False)`. But this will also make the scroll bar invisible. I also tried setting the scroll rate to 0 by using `rate_y` & `rate_x`, this also makes the scroll bar invisible. In short I want to show the scroll bar but make it do nothing.

Is there a way to capture the scroll events and make them to do nothing? I tried a hit and trial method by binding `myPanel` with [wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ScrollWinEvent.html#scrollwinevent) to execute a function that does nothing. Unfortunately it didn't worked (the scroll bar is still scrolling).

```
myPanel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
myPanel.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN, self.onScroll)

def onScroll(self, event):
    pass
```

Here is a quick & dirty code sample to play around and can be [downloaded too](https://db.tt/wQK3FDhd)! to avoid identation errors.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel


class GUI(wx.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
         screenSize = (400, 400)
         wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id, title, size=screenSize)
         myFont = wx.Font(15, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
         panelsSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
         sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
         myPanel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self, -1,style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
         myPanel.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN, self.onScroll)
         myPanel.SetupScrolling()
         panel1 = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(myPanel, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
         panel1.SetBackgroundColour('#FFFFFF')
         panel2 = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(myPanel, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
         panel2.SetBackgroundColour('#55F4FF')


         k = 0
         for i in range(1,7):
             sPanel ='Panel' +str(k)
             sPanel = wx.Panel(panel1)
             label = str(k)+'This is panel-1'
             text = wx.StaticText(sPanel, -1, label)
             text.SetForegroundColour('#0101DF')
             text.SetFont(myFont)
             sizer1.Add(sPanel, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
             sizer1.Add(wx.StaticLine(panel1), 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 0)
             k += 1

         panel1.SetSizer(sizer1)
         panelsSizer.Add(panel1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
         panelsSizer.Add(panel2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
         myPanel.SetSizer(panelsSizer)

     def onScroll(self, event):
            pass


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = GUI(parent=None, id=-1, title="Test")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Any suggestion? Thank you for your time.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a runnable example that we can paste and tweak.  It's not a big deal to wrap an app around the code you quoted, but it's not nothing either.

Comment: I instantiated a ScrolledPanel using the code above and didn't get scrollbars.  I haven't used one of these suckers before.  I was going to try event.Veto() inside onScroll.   Maybe you could try that...

Comment: @GreenAsJade I intentionally didn't want to provide a code because it makes the post lengthy which scares many users to even read it for once. :P However I updated my question with a sample code to play around.

Comment: Well, the guidelines for asking good questions suggest you supply a minimal working example... for a good reason :P.   However, in this case it didn't help, because it looks like you're out of luck.  Certainly, I had no more luck finding a solution than you: this widget seems to have the policy that if it's not scrolling, then it's not showing the bars.   And when you think about it: that maybe makes sense?   I wonder what is the experience that you're trying to create by having scroll bars that won't move?

Comment: @GreenAsJade  Well it is a long story why I am trying to do this stupid stuff. If will be difficult to explain here in comment. It will be nice to chat. Brief: I am trying to adjust my GUI. I have a topsizer that has 4 panels in it. Below this topsizer there is other sizer with 4 panels. But this sizer has a scroll bar. I am trying to align the panels in topsizer with the panels in below sizer. Due to scroll bar the panels in below sizer are moved bit to left. So, I added a scroll bar to the topsizer too to align them. Thats why I want to disable this scroll bar in topsizer. :(

Comment: Got it - makes sense.  Tough one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution to my problem. But I didn't quite understand that why it works. :P

I was reading tutorial on http://wiki.wxpython.org/AnotherTutorial#Events and found something interesting. The wiki states:

> wx.ScrollWinEvent event is generated, when we click on a built in
>   Scrollbar. Built-in Scrollbar is activated with the SetScrollbar()
>   method call. For stand-alone Scrollbars, there is another event type,
>   namely wx.ScrollEvent.

So I decided to setup a Built-in scroll bar and then I'll bind my `onScroll()` to do nothing when scroll bar is moved.  Now instead of creating a scrolledPanel I created a simple Panel.

```
myPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1,style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
```

Then I create a Built-in scroll bar using [setScrollbar()](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ScrollBar.html#ScrollBar.SetScrollbar).

```
myPanel.SetScrollbar(wx.VERTICAL, 0, 0, 2, 0)
```

Then I bind the `onScroll()` to the any [scrolling events](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ScrollEvent.html#scrollevent) that are happening.

```
myPanel.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN, self.OnScroll)
```

So, now you'll notice that the scroll bar on `myPanel` will do nothing on being clicked or dragged.

**Not understood by me:**

*You really don't need to intercept any scrolling events. You don't need to bind the onScroll(). Even if you don't bind the onScroll(), the scroll bar is still not responding to any clicking or dragging!* Perhaps I am missing something basic.

Here is the updated code to play around also available for [download](https://db.tt/mMWaRb97) to avoid indentation problems:

```
class GUI(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        screenSize = (400, 400)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id, title, size=screenSize)
        myFont = wx.Font(15, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
        panelsSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        myPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1,style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        #Uncommenting the following line has no effect on scroll bar behavior!
        #myPanel.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN, self.OnScroll)
        myPanel.SetScrollbar(wx.VERTICAL, 0, 0, 2, 0)
        panel1 = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(myPanel, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        panel1.SetBackgroundColour('#FFFFFF')
        panel2 = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(myPanel, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        panel2.SetBackgroundColour('#55F4FF')


        k = 0
        for i in range(1,10):
            sPanel ='Panel' +str(k)
            sPanel = wx.Panel(panel1)
            label = str(k)+'This is panel-1'
            text = wx.StaticText(sPanel, -1, label)
            text.SetForegroundColour('#0101DF')
            text.SetFont(myFont)
            sizer1.Add(sPanel, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
            sizer1.Add(wx.StaticLine(panel1), 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 0)
            k += 1

        panel1.SetSizer(sizer1)
        panelsSizer.Add(panel1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panelsSizer.Add(panel2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        myPanel.SetSizer(panelsSizer)

    def OnScroll(self, evt):
          print "Got it"
          pass



if __name__=='__main__':
   app = wx.App()
   frame = GUI(parent=None, id=-1, title="Test")
   frame.Show()
   app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: The reason this works is that in order to use stand alone scroll bars you _do_ have to bind them, and in the handler you have to read the thumb position and adjust the window display accordingly!  So it's a very nice solution for you ... just as long as standalone scroll bars look the same as the scroll bars in a scrolledpane.   You are safe with that for the current implementation of scrolledpane, but it is not guaranteed to be always true.   It's a lot nicer solution than the hack I provided :)

Answer (score 1):

Woo hoo, I read you solved it.

Meanwhile, this is the best awful hack I could come up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel


class GUI(wx.Frame):

     def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
         screenSize = (400, 400)
         wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id, title, size=screenSize)
         myFont = wx.Font(15, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
         panelsSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
         sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
         myPanel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self, -1,style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
         myPanel.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN, self.onScroll)
         myPanel.SetupScrolling()
         panel1 = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(myPanel, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
         panel1.SetBackgroundColour('#FFFFFF')
         panel2 = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(myPanel, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
         panel2.SetBackgroundColour('#55F4FF')


         k = 0
         for i in range(1,7):
             sPanel ='Panel' +str(k)
             sPanel = wx.Panel(panel1)
             label = str(k)+'This is panel-1'
             text = wx.StaticText(sPanel, -1, label)
             text.SetForegroundColour('#0101DF')
             text.SetFont(myFont)
             sizer1.Add(sPanel, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
             sizer1.Add(wx.StaticLine(panel1), 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 0)
             k += 1

         panel1.SetSizer(sizer1)
         panelsSizer.Add(panel1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
         panelsSizer.Add(panel2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
         myPanel.SetSizer(panelsSizer)
         self.scrolled_panel=myPanel 

     def onScroll(self, event):
        print "scroll event"
        for child in self.scrolled_panel.GetChildren():
           try:  
              child.SetThumbPosition(0)
              print "set child"
           except:
              print "oops,probably not a scrollbar :) "


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = GUI(parent=None, id=-1, title="Test")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

It doesn't stop them dragging the scrollbar, but it does pop it back after they let go.

**Update:  The code above only works on OSX, not Windows.**

Under OSX, the children of a ScrolledPanel are reported as:

```
wxWindowList: [<wx._controls.ScrollBar; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxScrollBar *' at 0x10068f830> >, <wx._controls.ScrollBar; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxScrollBar *' at 0x100691230> >, <wx._core.Window; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxWindow *' at 0x100691d20> >, <wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxPyScrolledWindow *' at 0x1004ac990> >, <wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxPyScrolledWindow *' at 0x1004af8e0> >]
```

It's the two ScrollBar's that my hack is targetting.

Under Windows, the same call returns:

```
wxWindowList: [<wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxPyScrolledWindo
w *' at 0x26837b8> >, <wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxPyScroll
edWindow *' at 0x26839b0> >]
```

This is much harder to understand.   Where are the scroll bars hiding?   I guess this is what you get for hacking into components that are supposed to be encapsulated for you :)

Comment: I'll test your code and let you know if it worked for me. I'll accept your answer if it worked for me despite that I have already found the solution. I'll also put my solution for other users. Thanks to GOD that there are still heedful persons like you on this planet who care for such weird questions. Please accept my gratitude :)

Comment: I tested your code I just added your method to my code. Unfortunately when I scroll the scroll bar the following error is displayed in the console and scroll bar is still scrolling fine. Any idea?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pss\Desktop\test2.py", line 43, in onScroll
    for child in self.scrolled_panel.GetChildren():
AttributeError: 'GUI' object has no attribute 'scrolled_panel'

Comment: @pss Sorry, you need self.scrolled_panel=myPanel in `__init__()`.  I just copied your code again, put that into `__init()__`, and put my code above into onScroll, and it works.

Comment: I edited my code now when I scroll the scroll bar I get "scroll event
oops,probably not a scrollbar :) 
oops,probably not a scrollbar :) " in console and scroll bar is still working.

Comment: Pfff - why didn't I just post my code in the first place.   I've edited it in.  I get 2 set childs (one for each scroll bar in the scrolled pane) and three "oops", for the other components in there.

Comment: This is really weird. It is still not working for me. I am using windows 7 OS, python v2.7, wxPython v3.0 Could that be the reason?

Comment: +1 for trying so hard and providing the details. Thanks a lot for your support and research.

Comment: Thx - as I said, in the end I think your answer is the best one :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this at the moment and it may be covered under what you have already tried, without more information I can't tell.

As far as I know there is no set way to disable scrolling without removing the scrollbar, what I would try in your position is, instead of using 'pass' when you fire the onScroll event, set the scrollbar position to 0 using [set position](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ScrollWinEvent.html?highlight=scroll#ScrollWinEvent.SetPosition), this might only reset the position after it has been moved though, I think you *should* be able to take control of the scroll event, I'm not sure why that isn't working for you.

Another option might be to set the scrollbars range to 0 or a very small number.

Comment: Thanks, but the set position trick didn't work. How can I set range? I am using scrolled panels. Please see my code above.